# CakePHP SMTP EMail Not Working on Server

Tags: email, cakephp, smtp

I am able to send SMTP Emails from my local server machine in CakePHP while I am not able to do the same on my GoDaddy live server, in CakePHP.

Any ideas for the same?

Thanks

**`Answer is below as per my experience with GoDaddy:`**

Below code is working for me over GoDaddy server using CakePHP SMTP Email:

Email.php file inside config folder - CakePHP 2.4 MVC version:

```
    // for Live Server GoDaddy.com domain
    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtpout.asia.secureserver.net', // important
        'port' => 465, // important
        #'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'no-reply@godaddy-domain.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        #'tls' => false,
        #'log' => false,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

And here is the controller file code below:

```
    // Controller Code to Send Actual Email
    // email configuration
    $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
    $Email->from(array('no-reply@godaddy-domain.com' => 'App Name'))
        ->sender('no-reply@godaddy-domain.com', 'App Name')
        ->to(array($email))
        ->bcc(array('xyz@xyz.com'))
        ->subject('Test Email from GoDaddy')
        ->emailFormat('both')
        ->send($hash.'<br><strong>My</strong> message 45 قبل الميلاد، مما يجعله أكثر من');
```

Hope it helps !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to check for an error message:

```
if(!$this->Email->send()) {
    CakeLog::write('debug', $this->Email->smtpError);
}
```

Then check the /app/tmp/logs/debug file on the server.